# If f is concave upward on [a,b], then is average value of f more than f(a+b/2)?

Tags: calculus, integration, average

I'm trying to solve a question concerning about average value of function.
A problem is

If $f$ is concave upward on $[a,b]$, then $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx > f((a+b)/2)$

I understand why it is true using diagram but I can't prove it.
I'm trying to use the fact f is concave upward so $f'$ is increasing but I couldn't go any further.
 Thank you in advance!

Comment: Should it be $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)dx$ on the LHS? Then it is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827772/convex-integral-inequality.

Comment: Otherwise it is wrong: set $f(x) = 1$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. I had a mistake and edited it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: But that has been answered in the Q&A that I linked to above.