# Inequality $\frac{1}{4}(e^{-4} + e^{-1}) \leq \int_1^2 e^{-x^2}dx \leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{-4}+e^{-1})$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Please help me to understand how to prove the inequality
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4}(e^{-4} + e^{-1}) \leq \int_1^2 e^{-x^2}dx \leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{-4}+e^{-1}). 
\end{equation}
Using the mean value theorem we can easily show that
\begin{equation}
e^{-4} \leq \int_1^2 e^{-x^2}dx \leq e^{-1}.
\end{equation}
But I completely don't understand how to obtain main inequality.

Comment: the second inequality can be dealt with convexity.

Comment: The convexity can be used for the first inequality as well by taking a tangent line at an appropriate point.

Comment: So, the second inequality follows from fact that $e^{-x^2}$ is convex on $[1,2]$ and answer in this post
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1827772/convex-integral-inequality
But how to deal with the first inequality?

Comment: Hermite-Hadamard inequality

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc do you have a better idea than the accepted answer? Sounds different

Comment: @BenjaminWang It is not different than the one used in the answer. Taking the tangent line at $3/2$ we get a trapeze with height $1$ and the arithmetic mean of the bases equal $f(3/2),$ where $f(x)=e^{-x^2}.$ So its area is equal $f(3/2).$ Now we are down to establishing that $f(3/2)> 4^{-1}(e^{-4}+e^{-1}).$ Perhaps there is a better choice of the point where we take the tangent line.

Comment: @BenjaminWang There is a much better choice of the tangent line. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will be proving the first inequality only as the second one has been answered in the post you mentioned in the comment. I do think this might be a crude way to prove the first inequality but I do not see any other method. Also, we will be using the first inequality of the aforementioned post.

So let us sketch this graph first and mark points $A(1,e^{-1}), B(2,e^{-4}), C(1,0), D(2,0)$. Let us mark an additional point $E$ with $x$-coordinate $x_E$ that satisfies $e^{-x^2} = \frac{e^{-4}+e^{-1}}{4}$, so this means $x_E= \sqrt{\ln(4) - \ln(e^{-4} + e^{-1})}$. Points $F$ and $G$ are points of intersection of horizontal line through $E$ with $AC$ and $BD$ (extended) respectively (the graph is visualised here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDRip.png).

Take $e^{-1}$ out from the $\ln$, so we are left with $\ln(1+e^{-3})-1$ and since $e^{-3} \ll 1$ we can use the approximation $\ln(1+x) \lessapprox x$.

Thus we get $x_E \gtrapprox \sqrt{1+\ln(4)-e^{-3}}$.

Again since $e^{-3} \ll\ln(4e)$ we can approximate (using binomial theorom) the square root as $\sqrt{1+x} \approx 1 + \frac{x}{2}$.

Thus we get $x_E\gtrapprox \sqrt{\ln(4e)}(1-\frac{e^{-3}}{2\ln(4e)})$.

As $\ln(4) \approx 1.38$, we have  $\ln(4e) \approx 2.38 > 2.25$.

Therefore $ \sqrt{\ln(4e)}>1.5 \implies x_E > 1.5$ (the contribution of $1-\frac{e^{-3}}{2\ln(4e)}$ is negligible as $e^{-3} \approx \frac{1}{20}$.

Therefore we found out that $x_E>\frac{1+2}{2}$.

Now we know area of rectangle FGDC = $\frac{e^{-4}+e^{-1}}{4}$.

But we know $(b-a)f(\frac{a+b}{2}) \leq \int_a^{b}f(x)dx$ if $f$ is convex (indeed $e^{-x^2}$ is convex for $x^2 \geq \frac{1}{2}$).

Thus, taking $a = 1, b = 2$ and $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$ to get $f(\frac{3}{2}) \leq \int_1^{2}e^{-x^2}dx$.

But since $f$ is decreasing on $[1,2]$ and $x_E>3/2$, we have $f(x_E)< f(\frac{3}{2}) \leq \int_1^{2}e^{-x^2}dx$.

By definition, $f(x_E)=e^{-x_E^2} = \frac{e^{-4}+e^{-1}}{4}$, so $ \frac{e^{-4}+e^{-1}}{4} < f(\frac{3}{2}) \leq \int_1^{2}e^{-x^2}dx$.

Hence we have proved the first (left side) of the inequality $\frac{e^{-4}+e^{-1}}{4} < \int_1^{2}e^{-x^2}dx$.

Comment: Thanks! There are some problems with latex, but the main idea is great.

Comment: Yeah honestly I don't know much about latex to format math, I just know the basic things and never really learned it. I just use it to make basic mathematical symbols (like integral greater than equal and all) and form (like exponential and all). Welcome

Answer (score 5):

The equation of the tangent line to the graph of $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ at $x=1$ is
$$y-e^{-1}=2e^{-1}(1-x)$$ as $f'(1)=-2e^{-1}.$ Observe that the point $(3/2,0)$ belongs to that line.
By the convexity of $f(x)$ the right triangle with vertices $(1,0),(1,e^{-1})$ and $(3/2,0)$   is located below the graph of $e^{-x^2}.$ Thus
$$\int\limits_1^{3/2}e^{-x^2}\,dx > {1\over 2}\cdot {1\over 2}\cdot e^{-1}={1\over 4}e^{-1}\tag{$*$}$$ On the other hand $$\int\limits_{3/2}^2e^{-x^2}\,dx >{1\over 2}e^{-4}\tag{$**$}$$ Adding $(*)$ and $(**)$ gives  a slightly stronger inequality than the first one in OP.

Concerning the second inequality observe that
$$\int\limits_1^2e^{-x^2}\,dx < \int\limits_1^2xe^{-x^2}\,dx={1\over 2}(e^{-1}-e^{-4})$$ so the result is stronger than the one in OP.

**Remark** Considering the tangent line at $3/2$ we can substantially improve $(**)$   $$\int\limits_{3/2}^2e^{-x^2}\,dx>{1\over 6}e^{-9/4}$$ The coefficient ${1\over 3}$ shows up as the tangent line cross the line $y=0$ at $\left ({3\over 2}+{1\over 3},0\right ).$

Comment: Nice. Very natural solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach. Note that the inequality $$\frac 1 2xe^{-x^2}\leq e^{-x^2}\leq xe^{-x^2}~{\rm for~}1\leq x\leq 2$$ implies $$\int_1^2 \frac 1 2xe^{-x^2}~dx\leq \int_1^2 e^{-x^2}~dx\leq \int_1^2 xe^{-x^2}~dx$$
$$\Rightarrow \left.-\frac 1 4e^{-x^2}\right|_1^2\leq \int_1^2 e^{-x^2}~dx\leq \left.-\frac 1 2e^{-x^2}\right|_1^2~({\rm by~the~FTC})$$
$$\Rightarrow -\frac 1 4e^{-4}+\frac 1 4e^{-1}\leq \int_1^2 e^{-x^2}~dx\leq -\frac 1 2e^{-4}+\frac 1 2e^{-1},$$ hence the right inequality of the original problem is immediate. To get the left inequality in the original statement, one refines the process by applying the inequality
$$\int_1^{3/2}\frac 2 3xe^{-x^2}~dx+\int_{3/2}^2\frac 1 2xe^{-x^2}~dx\leq \int_1^2 e^{-x^2}~dx$$
$$\Leftrightarrow -\frac 1{12}e^{-9/4}+\frac 13e^{-1}-\frac 1 4e^{-4}\leq \int_1^2 e^{-x^2}~dx.\tag{1}$$ But one can show that $$-\frac 1{12}e^{-9/4}+\frac 13e^{-1}-\frac 1 4e^{-4}>\frac 3 4e^{-4}+\frac 1 4e^{-1},\tag{2}$$ which together with (1) gives a sharper lower bound in the original statement. It suffices now to prove (2), which is equivalent to $$e^3-e^{7/4}>12,$$ which in turn is implied by the following inequalities $$e^3-e^{7/4}>e(e^2-e)>e(2.7^2-2.8)>(2.7)(2.7^2-2.8)> 12,$$ hence (2) is proven and one has the sharper lower bound for the original integral: $$\frac 3 4e^{-4}+\frac 1 4e^{-1}<\int_1^2 e^{-x^2}.$$ Similarly, one has $$\int_1^2 e^{-x^2}~dx\leq \int_1^{3/2} xe^{-x^2}~dx+\int_{3/2}^2 \frac 2 3xe^{-x^2}~dx$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \int_1^2 e^{-x^2}~dx\leq -\frac 16e^{-9/4}+\frac 1 2e^{-1}-\frac 1 3e^{-4},$$ where the right hand side satisfies $$-\frac 1 6e^{-9/4}+\frac 1 2e^{-1}-\frac 1 3e^{-4}<\frac 1 2e^{-1}-\frac 5 4e^{-4}.\tag{3}$$ Hence one gets a sharper upper bound: $$\int_1^2 e^{-x^2}~dx<\frac 1 2e^{-1}-\frac 5 4e^{-4}.$$ Note that (3) is equivalent to $$11<2e^{7/4}~{\rm or~}11^4<16e^7,$$ which is implied by $$11^4<16(2.7)^7<16e^7,$$ hence everything is proven.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A\equiv(1,e^{-1}),B\equiv(1,0),C\equiv(\frac{3}{2},0),D\equiv(2,0),E\equiv(2,e^{-4})$.

Line joining the points $A$ and $C$ is clearly tangent to the curve and because of concavity
($f''(x)<0)$ the curve lies above its tangents and below its chords.

So the $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle CDE$ lie below the curve and if we consider the trapezium $ABDE$ we find that the chord $DE$ lies above the curve.

So, $$\operatorname{Area}(\triangle ABC)+\operatorname{Area}(\triangle CDE)\leq \int_1^2e^{-x^2}dx\leq \operatorname{Area}(\text{trapezium }  ABDE) $$

$$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}-1\right)e^{-1}+\frac{1}{2}\left(2-\frac{3}{2}\right)e^{-4}\leq \int_1^2e^{-x^2}dx\leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{-1}+e^{-4})(2-1)$$

$$\frac{1}{4}(e^{-1}+e^{-4})\leq \int_1^2e^{-x^2}dx\leq \frac{1}{2}(e^{-1}+e^{-4})$$